# i make my usb bootable of ubuntu but it is not working on acer 4738z

Tags: boot, usb, acer

i am in serious problem. i have acer aspire 4738z. i am willing to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 on it and for that i made my usb bootable through the software which is mentioned in Ubuntu guide but it is not recognized by the laptop at startup and when my old windows is opened i run wibi from it but after restarting it doesn't work.
help me please

Comment: Wubi is known to contain lots of bugs. You should try UNetBootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ and create a Ubuntu Live stick. DO you use UEFI? If yes, disable secure boot. What Windows are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Wubi no longer works, and will just restart the system. You should either burn the iso file to a dvd, or use unetbootin to create a bootable usb stick.